# Linux interrupt handling: in SA_SHIRQ or IRQF_SHARED flag who will decide priority(user/kernel)?

Tags: linux, kernel, driver, device, interrupt

in request_irq() suppose I am sharing one irq no with two handler function, so who will decide which handler should execute first and which should second? whether we can change the priority of handler that should execute first?

Answer (score 4):

SA_SHIRQ is depleted for years.
use IRQF_SHARED.
you can check kernel  code interrupt.h